# В столбце Excel сделать ссылку на одну ячейку

Tags: excel

Мне нужно что бы при изменении значения в ячейке это число подставлялось бы в формуле в одном столбце.

Т.е. к примеру есть ячейка b1 там значение 100. Есть столбец  d1:d1000. Надо что бы во всем столбце была ссылка на эту одну ячейку. (Весь столбец имеет значение 100). Если я меняю значение в ячейке b1 во всем столбце значение тоже должно поменяться. Пробовал копировать формулу и вставлять, но Excel слишком умный, все время норовит перескочить в нижние ячейки.

Comment: [**=$B$1**](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA-981f5871-7864-42cc-b3f0-41ffa10cc6fc)?

Comment: спасибо, сделаешь в виде ответа помечу плюсом и решением

Comment: Брось, для хорошего ответа нужно описать и абсолютные ссылки, и "формулу массива", и вариант с =D2 в ячейке D1... Много писать. А всё это не раз описано и в Справке, и инете, и в книжках для чайников... Проще весь вопрос удалить

Comment: Почитайте об абсолютных и относительных ссылках - как раз в тему. Для данного случая формулу можно сократить аж на 20% - на целый знак :)  `=B$1`. Еще вариант: `D1=B1` ,  `D2=D1`, протянуть формулу `D2` вниз